# How to get only one vertically centered equation number in align environment with two equations

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, numbering, align

What I have are two equations with `align` and I want one single equation number to refer to this system of equations. To illustrate, I have

```
\begin{align}
  dr_t &= \kappa ( \theta - r_t ) dt + \sigma_r r^{\xi} dW_t \\
  dA_t &= \mu A_t dt + \sigma_A^{\alpha} dZ_t,
\end{align}
```

[image: 1]
and I want neither

```
\begin{align}
  dr_t &= \kappa ( \theta - r_t ) dt + \sigma_r r^{\xi} dW_t \nonumber \\
  dA_t &= \mu A_t dt + \sigma_A^{\alpha} dZ_t,
\end{align}
```

[image]
nor

```
\begin{align}
  dr_t &= \kappa ( \theta - r_t ) dt + \sigma_r r^{\xi} dW_t \\
  dA_t &= \mu A_t dt + \sigma_A^{\alpha} dZ_t, \nonumber
\end{align}
```

[image]

but having a single number in the middle. I know this can be achieved by nesting an `array` inside of an equation but then some symbols (sums, etc.) look differently and I thought there had to be a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 221, accepted):

Use `aligned` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  dr_t &= \kappa ( \theta - r_t ) dt + \sigma_r r^{\xi} dW_t \\
  dA_t &= \mu A_t dt + \sigma_A^{\alpha} dZ_t, 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @TH. I have a question: Is it possible to place text between these two equations?

Comment: @TH. @Paul Koer You need `\\ ` after `dW_t`, otherwise both equations will be concatenated in the same line

Comment: Environments `equation` and `align` serve similar kinds of purposes. Whereas the purpose of `split` or `aligned`is quite distinct: i.e. they typically fit _inside_ `equation`, `align*`, etc.

Answer (score 67):

Here's a slightly better way to do this (IMO):

Using the `split` environment within an `align` will produce one equation number, vertically centered within the `split` (so long as there's not a page break involved, as discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42726/align-but-show-one-equation-number-at-the-end?rq=1)).

Note that you can have individual labels for each equation by adding `\label{}` to the end of each line before the line break `\\`

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document} 

\begin{align}
  E_1&=A+B \label{eq:1}\\
   \begin{split}
    E_2&=(C-D)E_1 \label{eq:2}\\
    &\quad +[(1-R)+R(1-Y)\\
    &\quad +\pi(1-\delta)]E_2\\
    &\quad +F\cdot E_3
   \end{split}\\
  E_3 &=(\pi\cdot \chi)-(R\cdot E_1)-(RY\delta\cdot E_2) \label{eq:3}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Answer (score 43):

This is really a comment on TH.'s accepted answer (which should stay that way).  Using just one `aligned` doesn't work if you have multiple columns: they are separated by only a small space, since `aligned` "shrinks to fit".  The workaround is to use one `aligned` *per column*, and wrap the whole thing in a larger `align`, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 \begin{align}
  \begin{aligned}
   x &= y \\       f(x) &= f(y)
  \end{aligned}
  &&
  \begin{aligned}
   a &= b \\       g(a) &= g(b)
  \end{aligned}
 \end{align}
\end{document}
```

This should produce two pairs of equations, each aligned at the equals sign, and with one equation number centered between the lines.

[image]

Comment: It would seem better to wrap the whole thing in a larger `equation`, and separated the `aligned` by using a `\quad` or two.

Comment: I disagree; explicit positioning is exactly what we use aligned to avoid. If you want greater control (and I don't think this is visually critical enough to warrant designing your document code around this goal) you can play with the column spacing.

Comment: One problem is that when the equations on different columns have different heights, the horizontal alignment gets screwed.

Answer (score 9):

Using

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  dr_t &= \kappa ( \theta - r_t ) dt + \sigma_r r^{\xi} dW_t \\
  dA_t &= \mu A_t dt + \sigma_A^{\alpha} dZ_t,
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

will produce one equation number that is vertically centered on the group of equations.