# Show equation number only once in align environment

Tags: equations, align

I want the equation number to be shown only at the last line, or better, somewhere in the middle of all. So instead of `(1), (2), ...` only `(1)`.
I use `\begin{align} ... \end{align}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get only one vertically centered equation number in align environment with two equations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/how-to-get-only-one-vertically-centered-equation-number-in-align-environment-with)

Answer (score 262, accepted):

You can use the `split` environment from the `amsmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
  a &= b \\
  &=c \\
  &=d \\
  &=e
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: effect of using split in align to avoid excess numbering]

Comment: you could also simply put `\nonumber` at the end of each equation line for which you don't want an equation no.

Comment: You could also see this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/how-to-get-only-one-vertically-centered-equation-number-in-align-environment-with/17483#17483

Comment: @prettygully: if the number of lines is even, then `\notag` (or `\nonumber`) won't vertically center the tag.

Comment: @prettygully: I think you should also write your comment as an answer. @Gonzalo Medina: sometimes you want the number at the end, rather than centered; I often do so. (While the OP prefers centered, not everyone will.)

Comment: is there a simple way to adapt this solution for multiple alignment columns? It looks like `\begin{align*}\begin{split} A &= B & C&= D \\ A &= B & C&= D
\end{split}\end{align*}` doesn't work.

Answer (score 272):

Use `\nonumber` to do so:

```
\begin{align}
  a & b \nonumber \\ % no number is shown
  c & d \\ % there is a number
  e & f \nonumber % no number
\end{align}
```

[image: align output demonstrating use of \nonumber to avoid two of three lines getting numbered]

Comment: What if I only have two lines?..

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb not sure if this is what you mean, but you can use `\nonumber` in an align environment with only two lines. Only the line without `\nonumber` ending it will have number in the output

Comment: @SkeletonBow - They presumably mean "how can I get the equation number vertically centered if there are only two lines (or any even number of lines)?". The split environment does this (but doesn't work with multiple alignment columns), but \nonumber does not.

Comment: It looks like `\nonumber` doesn't work within the `\added{}` command from the `changes` package.

Answer (score 31):

You can use the `aligned` environment from the `amsmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\begin{split}
  m &=n \\
    &=o \\
    &=p \\
    &=q
\end{split}\\
\begin{aligned}
  a &=b + 1 \\
  c &=d \\
  e &=f \\
  g &=h
\end{aligned}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image: effect of gather with sub-structures using split and aligned on alignment and numbering]

This is generally recommended for straightforward expressions rather than embedding a sub-structure within `align`.  See the user's manual for `amsmath` (`amsldoc.pdf` on ctan or type `texdoc amsmath` if you have a tex live installation).

Edit: changed `equation` environment to `gather` to allow multiple sub-structures, and added an example of `split` as requested.  Since single letters on either side of the equals sign will give the illusion that *everything* is aligned, I lengthened one line to show that the alignments of the two sub-structures are really offset from one another.

This result will get two equation numbers; either may be removed by use of `\notag`, but the positioning will not be optimal.  Sadly, I don't have a solution for that.

Comment: Mildly ironic that in an answer to a question on alignment, you had an error in your code alignment!  A case of _misalliance_ (in tribute to Britain's answer to Tom Lehrer).

Comment: I think this is the right answer, but with the wrong example. To typeset a multi-line equation such as a = b = c = d = e, you should *not* use anything from the align family, but something like split. Could you perhaps change the example so that it is something like "a = b, c = d, e = f, g = h", so that it is clearly multiple equations that you want to align. This is not just semantics; there might be a difference in the vertical spacing, and you should use the right command for the right purpose.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, something that has the nice symmetric labelling of `split` but also supports multiple columns like `align`.

Answer (score 16):

I realize this question is now quite old, but I've found wrapping the nested `equation`/`aligned` in an environment handy since I want single numbers for multi-line equations quite a bit. One hitch is that LaTeX will add a space to the next line unless you do something about it. Here's an `nalign` environment that is like `align` but with one (centered) equation number for all the lines.

```
\newenvironment{nalign}{
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
}{
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
    \ignorespacesafterend
}
```