# label multiple lines of equations

Tags: equations, labels

Suppose I have the equations

```
\begin{align}
 f(x) = x^2
 g(x) = \exp( x )
\end{align}
```

I would like to use on single label for these lines, and ideally the equation number would be placed vertically between these two lines.

Although this question appears very basic, I have not found an explanation neither via search engines, nor on this website.

Comment: Amsldoc is a good source for all equation-related things

Comment: there's an answer in this question: [Show equation number only once in align environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17571/579)

Answer (score 38):

The very thing you want is the `split` environment, provided by the `amsmath` class.

**Sample code.**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=90mm]{geometry}% <-- better demonstrates the vertical alignment
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

Eqn.~\eqref{eqn:eqlabel} has a single label split
across the two equations, as you can see here:
\begin{align}
\label{eqn:eqlabel}
\begin{split}
 f(x) &= x^2 ,
\\
 g(x) &= \exp( x ) .
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

**Result.**

[image: Sample document using the split environment]

Comment: Note:  You can also use *split* not just within the *align* environment, but also within *eqnarray*.

Comment: That's as maybe, but you should not use eqnarray.

Comment: forgot double slash `\\ ` : `f(x) &= x^2 ,\\ g(x) &= \exp( x )` .

Comment: How to align equ no. (1) with last line?

Comment: @Mr.EU: in that case you should use `equation` together with `aligned`, as in `\begin{equation}
\label{eqn:eqlabel}
\begin{aligned}[b]
 f(x) &= x^2 ,
\\
 g(x) &= \exp( x ) .
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}`. Note the `[b]` after the `{aligned}`: this puts the equation number on the bottom line (more specifically, it aligns the baseline of the bottom of the entire `aligned` environment with the baseline of whatever comes before and after it in the equation, such as the equation number).

Answer (score 20):

You can use an `aligned` or `gathered` environment inside an `equation`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:t}
  \begin{aligned}
    f(x) &= x^2\\        
    g(x) &= \exp(x)
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:u}
  \begin{gathered}
    f(x) = x^2\\        
    g(x) = \exp(x)
  \end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: forgot double slash `\\ ` :  `f(x) = x^2\\       g(x) = \exp( x )`

Comment: @IvanKush Thanks for pointing it out.  I am 100% certain I didn't forget them, because the code was cut and pasted from the file used to compile the image.  However, they had certainly disappeared from the posting.

Comment: FYI, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7168/double-backslashes-disappear-from-code

Comment: I like this one the best. I've had issues in the past with \begin{split}.