# Is there an opposite to \nonumber?

Tags: equations, align

Usually I set equations using the `align` environment together with `\nonumber` for those few lines that shall not have a number, or the `align*` environment if no equation shall be numbered. But what if there are only few equations in a an `align` block that shall be numbered? In that case, adding `\nonumber` to almost all lines is a bit annoying, so is there anything like `\donumber` in an `align*` environment?

Comment: You may be using the wrong tools and possibly `split` or `aligned` might help you. Can you give an example of a use case?

Comment: Related questions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42726/align-but-show-one-equation-number-at-the-end?lq=1 http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17528/show-equation-number-only-once-in-align-environment?rq=1

Comment: @egreg A longer derivation of an expression where e.g. two immediate results are important enough to deserve a label.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks, the `\numberthis` command (`\newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}`) from [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42728/430) solves it, marking as duplicate