# One multiline equation and many single line equations inside align environment

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

Here is a MWE.

```
\begin{align}
  \label{eq:4}
  \begin{aligned}
    r'_0(s)
      & =\gamma \Omega_{i} \exp(\gamma s \Omega_{i}) r_0(0)
      \exp( -\mu s \Omega_{i} \\
      & \qquad - \mu \exp(\gamma s \Omega_i) r_0(0)
      \exp(-\mu s \Omega_{i}) \Omega_{i} \\
      & = \gamma \Omega_{i} r_0(s) - \mu r_0(s) \Omega_{i} \\
      \end{aligned} \\
  {add another multiline equation like the first two lines here}
\end{align}
```

But the output is not ideal because the equation number in the second line is below the actual equation. It is probably expecting another multiline equation. I would like to keep the equation number on the same line as the second equation. How can I fix this?

**Edit**: I intend to add a third line which once again will have a multiline equation. So I must use the aligned environment. Therefore simply turning off the equation numbers won't solve this problem. Therefore I do not think it is not a duplicate of [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17528/show-equation-number-only-once-in-align-environment). Actually, I got inspiration from the answer to this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44451/25665). This question has a parallel with that question if any.

Here is the output from the above piece of code
[image]

Comment: Delete \\ after \end{aligned}, and then (3.14) will disappear.

Comment: If I delete it then the equation number completely disappears.

Comment: @minibuffer Is my answer not enough to solve your problem? If so, please updater your answer with more equations or a way that makes clear that you ask for something else than the given duplicate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it using `\nonumber` command inside a single align:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
    r'_0(s)
      & =\gamma \Omega_{i} \exp(\gamma s \Omega_{i}) r_0(0)
      \exp( -\mu s \Omega_{i} \nonumber\\
      & \qquad - \mu \exp(\gamma s \Omega_i) r_0(0)
      \exp(-\mu s \Omega_{i}) \Omega_{i} \label{first}\\
      & = \gamma \Omega_{i} r_0(s) - \mu r_0(s) \Omega_{i} \label{second}
  \end{align}

  the equation \eqref{first} is above the equation \eqref{second}.
\end{document}
```

I think you can expand this way in your needs.

Output:
[image]

EDIT: After OP's edit and after accepting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
    &\begin{aligned}\label{first}
    r'_0(s)
      & =\gamma \Omega_{i} \exp(\gamma s \Omega_{i}) r_0(0)
      \exp( -\mu s \Omega_{i} \\
      & \qquad - \mu \exp(\gamma s \Omega_i) r_0(0)
      \exp(-\mu s \Omega_{i}) \Omega_{i} 
     \end{aligned}\\
    &\begin{aligned}\label{second}
      \phantom{ r'_0(s)}& = \gamma \Omega_{i} r_0(s) - \mu r_0(s) \Omega_{i}
      \end{aligned}
  \end{align}

  the equation \eqref{first} is above the equation \eqref{second}.
\end{document}
```

This is a way used aligned environment with the next output:

[image]

As you can see the numbers are vertically centered. Also I have not reason to use the aligned but adding for OP's "unknown specific needs" :P

Comment: I added a way with aligned... but not really used it... You may adjust it to your needs... (You accepted during my edit... )

Comment: Your second edit is more like what I wanted. This works. :)

Comment: Nice... Glad that helped... Happy TeXing...