# Nesting environments when trying to define an align-like environment which carries one single equation number

Tags: align, environments, split

I am trying to define a new `align`-like environment that, in the spirit of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17528/show-equation-number-only-once-in-align-environment/17529#17529), displays only one single equation number for the entire multi-line equation. As for nesting the `align` and `split` environments I consulted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381929/creating-a-newenvironment-that-contains-nested-environments) but I can't get it to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{alignOne}{\align\split}{\endsplit\endalign}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignOne}
  a &= b \\
  &=c \\
  &=d \\
  &=e
\end{alignOne}

\end{document}
```

The error message is

```
Missing } inserted. [    \end{alignOne}]
```

and a similar error message shows up when I replace `\split` with `\begin{split}` and `\endsplit` with `\end{split}`.

How do I get this to work? What is the general way to nest environments in `\newenvironment` definitions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works as expected:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{alignOne}
  {\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}}
  {\end{aligned}\end{equation}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignOne}
  a &= b \\
    &= c \\
    &= d \\
    &= e
\end{alignOne}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! May I ask why my approach did not work and whether there is a general way to nest environments within `\newenvironment`?

Comment: @balu: At this point I'm not exactly sure. In some instances one can try using the command-form of an environment, but in other instances one should/can use the full environment form. `align`-like environment capture the entire contents of the environment in order to read it more than once. This capturing is over predicated on the existence of an explicit `\end{<env>}`.