# Separate subequations over two lines each

Tags: align, minipage, subequations

My working example is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{mleftright}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\label{ComputationInnProd}
    \begin{align}
        \label{ComputationInnProdDiscr}
        \langle \underbrace{ \mleft( \sum_{\alpha'} \psi_{\alpha'}^* \bra{\alpha'} \mright) }_{\bra{\psi}} \vert \underbrace{ \mleft( \sum_{\alpha''} \varphi_{\alpha''} \ket{\alpha''} \mright) }_{ \ket{\phi} } \rangle = \sum_{\alpha', \alpha''} \psi_{\alpha'}^* \varphi_{\alpha''} \braket{\alpha' \vert \alpha''} = \\
        \sum_{\alpha',\alpha''} \psi_{\alpha'}^* \varphi_{\alpha''} \delta_{\alpha' \alpha''} = \sum_{\alpha'} \psi_{\alpha'}^* \varphi_{\alpha'},  \\
        \label{ComputationInnProdCont}
        \langle \underbrace{ \mleft( \int {d\alpha'} \psi^* \mleft( \alpha' \mright) \bra{\alpha'} \mright) }_{\bra{\psi}} \vert \underbrace{ \mleft( \int {d\alpha''} \varphi \mleft( \alpha'' \mright) \ket{\alpha''} \mright) }_{ \ket{\phi} } \rangle = \int {d\alpha'} \int {d\alpha''} \psi^* \mleft( \alpha' \mright) \varphi \mleft( \alpha'' \mright) \braket{\alpha' \vert \alpha''} = \\
        \int {d\alpha'} \int {d\alpha''} \psi^* \mleft( \alpha' \mright) \varphi \mleft( \alpha'' \mright) \delta \mleft( \alpha' - \alpha'' \mright) = \int {d\alpha'} \psi^* \mleft( \alpha' \mright) \varphi \mleft( \alpha' \mright),
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

I want the first two equations to belong to subequation 0.1a and have the `ComputationInnProdDiscr` label and the latter two to be grouped as subequation 0.1b and have the label `ComputationInnProdCont` for future reference.

This code produces the following output:
[image]

I've marked each of the equality signs that I want to be aligned with each other in red and green, respectively. I'm also open to suggestions for what would make this more readable because it does not look particularly pretty.

Comment: Use `\begin{split}` `\end{split}`. See here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17528/show-equation-number-only-once-in-align-environment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to applying some judiciously-chosen `\notag` instructions, you should also reconsider the objective of displaying the subequations across just 2 lines. I think things would be a lot clearer, and less cramped, if they were typeset across 3 lines each.

Note the use of the `\smash[b]{...}` directives. They serve to reduce (actually, eliminate) the extra vertical whitespace that would otherwise get inserted after lines 1 and 4.

Finally, don't overuse `\mleft` and `\mright`. (In the following solution, they aren't used at all.) On the other hand, don't neglect to increase the sizes of the angle brackets either.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath,braket}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{3} % just for this example
\begin{subequations}
\label{ComputationInnProd}
\begin{align}
\label{ComputationInnProdDiscr}
\smash[b]{\biggl\langle 
\underbrace{ \biggl( \sum_{\alpha'} \psi_{\alpha'}^* \bra{\alpha'} \biggr) }_{\bra{\psi}} \biggm\vert 
\underbrace{ \biggl( \sum_{\alpha''} \varphi_{\alpha''} \ket{\alpha''} \biggr) }_{ \ket{\phi} } \biggr\rangle} 
&= \sum_{\alpha', \alpha''} \psi_{\alpha'}^* \varphi^{}_{\alpha''} \braket{\alpha' \vert \alpha''}  \notag\\
&=\sum_{\alpha',\alpha''} \psi_{\alpha'}^* \varphi^{}_{\alpha''} \delta_{\alpha' \alpha''} \notag\\
&= \sum_{\alpha'} \psi_{\alpha'}^* \varphi^{}_{\alpha'}\,\text{;}  \\
\label{ComputationInnProdCont}
\smash[b]{\biggl\langle 
\underbrace{ \biggl( \int\!d\alpha' \psi^* ( \alpha') \bra{\alpha'} \biggr) }_{\bra{\psi}} \biggm\vert 
\underbrace{ \biggl( \int\!d\alpha'' \varphi ( \alpha'') \ket{\alpha''} \biggr) }_{ \ket{\phi} } \biggr\rangle}  
&= \int\!d\alpha' \int\!d\alpha''\, \psi^* ( \alpha') \varphi ( \alpha'') \braket{\alpha' \vert \alpha''}  \notag \\
&=\int\!d\alpha' \int\!d\alpha''\, \psi^* ( \alpha') \varphi ( \alpha'') \delta ( \alpha' - \alpha'') \notag \\
&= \int\!d\alpha'\, \psi^* ( \alpha') \varphi ( \alpha')\,.
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's my proposal.

1. Remove *all* `\mleft` and `\mright`.
2. Use manual sizing for `\langle` and `\rangle`.
3. Divide the alignment into two nested `aligned` environments.
4. Smash the bottom when the underbrace is involved.

The code:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{braket}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\label{ComputationInnProd}
\begin{align}
\label{ComputationInnProdDiscr}
&\begin{aligned}[b]
\smash[b]{
\biggl\langle
  \underbrace{
     \sum_{\alpha'} \psi_{\alpha'}^* \bra{\alpha'} 
  }_{\bra{\psi}}
\biggm|
  \underbrace{
     \sum_{\alpha''} \varphi_{\alpha''} \ket{\alpha''} 
  }_{\ket{\phi}}
\biggr\rangle
}% end smash
&= \sum_{\alpha', \alpha''} \psi_{\alpha'}^* \varphi_{\alpha''} \braket{\alpha' \vert \alpha''}
\\
&= \sum_{\alpha',\alpha''} \psi_{\alpha'}^* \varphi_{\alpha''} \delta_{\alpha' \alpha''}
 = \sum_{\alpha'} \psi_{\alpha'}^* \varphi_{\alpha'}, 
\end{aligned}
\\[2ex]
\label{ComputationInnProdCont}
&\begin{aligned}[b]
\smash[b]{
\biggl\langle
  \underbrace{
     \int d\alpha'\, \psi^* (\alpha') \bra{\alpha'} 
  }_{\bra{\psi}}
\biggm|
  \underbrace{
     \int d\alpha''\, \varphi (\alpha'') \ket{\alpha''} 
  }_{ \ket{\phi} }
\biggr\rangle
}% end smash
&= \int d\alpha' \int d\alpha''\, \psi^* (\alpha') \varphi (\alpha'')
        \braket{\alpha' \vert \alpha''}
\\
&= \int d\alpha' \int d\alpha''\, \psi^* (\alpha') \varphi (\alpha'')
        \delta (\alpha' - \alpha'')
\\
&= \int d\alpha'\, \psi^* (\alpha') \varphi (\alpha'),
\end{aligned}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Note the `\,` to separate the various differentials from the function or a following differential.

[image]

Comment: don't you define \ub but then never use it?

Comment: @MarkusGratis Oh, that remained from a previous attempt.

Answer (score 2):

Elad Den was right in forwarding me to the linked thread on tex stack exchange.
The solution for this specific case is:

```
\begin{subequations}
\label{ComputationInnProd}
    \begin{align}
        \begin{split}
        \label{ComputationInnProdDiscr}
        \langle \underbrace{ \mleft( \sum_{\alpha'} \psi_{\alpha'}^* \bra{\alpha'} \mright) }_{\bra{\psi}} \vert \underbrace{ \mleft( \sum_{\alpha''} \varphi_{\alpha''} \ket{\alpha''} \mright) }_{ \ket{\phi} } \rangle & = \sum_{\alpha', \alpha''} \psi_{\alpha'}^* \varphi_{\alpha''} \braket{\alpha' \vert \alpha''} = \\
        \sum_{\alpha',\alpha''} \psi_{\alpha'}^* \varphi_{\alpha''} \delta_{\alpha' \alpha''} & = \sum_{\alpha'} \psi_{\alpha'}^* \varphi_{\alpha'},
        \end{split}
    \end{align}
    \begin{align}
        \begin{split}
        \label{ComputationInnProdCont}
        \langle \underbrace{ \mleft( \int {d\alpha'} \psi^* \mleft( \alpha' \mright) \bra{\alpha'} \mright) }_{\bra{\psi}} \vert \underbrace{ \mleft( \int {d\alpha''} \varphi \mleft( \alpha'' \mright) \ket{\alpha''} \mright) }_{ \ket{\phi} } \rangle & = \int {d\alpha'} \int {d\alpha''} \psi^* \mleft( \alpha' \mright) \varphi \mleft( \alpha'' \mright) \braket{\alpha' \vert \alpha''} = \\
        \int {d\alpha'} \int {d\alpha''} \psi^* \mleft( \alpha' \mright) \varphi \mleft( \alpha'' \mright) \delta \mleft( \alpha' - \alpha'' \mright) & = \int {d\alpha'} \psi^* \mleft( \alpha' \mright) \varphi \mleft( \alpha' \mright),
        \end{split}
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

[image]

Encapsulating everything in one align environment is ambigous regarding the labels and leaving out the aligns (only split) alltogether produces an error.