# Have one centred equation number in the flalign enviroment

Tags: equations, amsmath

I want to use the `flalign` so I can have left aligned text in-between equations. For example

```
\begin{flalign}
    && f &= ma&\\
    \text{Which we may express as} \\
    && f &= m \frac{dv}{dt}
\end{flalign}
```

However this gives an equation number for every line, including the `\text{...}`.

How can I have one equation number that appears centered for the rendered result, as with any other equation number.

Comment: One possible solution is `\nonumber` on the lines one doesn't wish to see an equation number.

Comment: [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17528/show-equation-number-only-once-in-align-environment) might help.

Comment: Will your readers understand what the number at the level of the textual insertion refers to?

Comment: I sure hope so!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
    && f &= ma&             \notag  \\
\text{Which we may express as}      \\
    && f &= m \frac{dv}{dt} \notag
\end{flalign}

\bigskip\noindent%
You may consider the following solution:
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:sys}
    \begin{align}
f &= ma                             \\
\intertext{Which we may express as}
f &= m \frac{dv}{dt}         
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution, is there a way to keep the equation centred on the page, while keeping the in-equation text left justified?

Comment: @Q.P., the second example provide this, Yes, it hasn't common equation number on the vertical middle, however it is replaced by two (to my opinion) more meaningful equation sub numbering.