# How can I number a few equations together

Tags: equations, numbering, align

i would like to write few equations, but all the equations will get only once numbered and in the middle (right side) of the equations. e.q. if i write 3 equations, the number will be to the right of the second equation line and if i have 2 equations, then the number will between the two equations and at the right side.

in addition i would like to have something like "&" (align) that i could align my equations at certain points.

Example:

```
a   = x_{ij}
                  (1)
b_j = y_j
```

where of course the number of equation doesn't take a all line space.

Comment: Would simply using \notag in  conjucture with \begin{align*} 
or \tag with \begin{align} solve your problem ?

Comment: See also [How to get only one vertically centered equation number in align environment with two equations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/how-to-get-only-one-vertically-centered-equation-number-in-align-environment-wit).

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar but then the tag won't be vertically centered if there's an even number of lines in the equation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `amsmath` package provides the `split` environment. You can use a `split` environment inside an `align` environment or inside an `equation` environment; a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
  a   &= x_{ij} \\
  b_j &= y_j 
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You do not need `align` to get alignment, your example will work fine with an `equation` instead of `align`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes; however, for consistency reasons, I always use `array` when I use the alignment characters `&`. I will rephrase my answer.

Comment: I wouldn't advise to use `align` other than when it's necessary and moreover the usage of `split` is "wrong", as LaTeX will never use `\abovedisplayshortskip` with it. With `aligned` inside `equation` it will, if the line preceding the alignment is short; this is preferable for a singly numbered display.

Answer (score 19):

The **amsmath** package has many facilities, among which the `aligned` environment that does similarly to `align`, but produces a block usable in a bigger formula:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  a   &= x_{ij} \\
  b_j &= y_j 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

What's the difference with `split`? That `aligned`, like `align`, allows many alignment points.

Answer (score 3):

Although [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) functionality is preferred, there are a multitude of ways this can be achieved. Here's one using only an `array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}% To spread out the equations
  \begin{array}{r@{\;}l}
    a =& x_{ij} \\
    b_j =& y_j
  \end{array} \label{eq}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

It has the same layout - in terms of input - to the `align` environment. Moreover, it now also straight-forward to combine the equations using a brace (say) - achieved using a `\left.` and `\right\}` pair:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}% To spread out the equations
  \left.\begin{array}{r@{\;}l}
    a =& x_{ij} \\
    b_j =& y_j
  \end{array}\right\} \label{eq}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

`rcases` (from [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)) also provides the above functionality, but is usually intended for a different purpose. As such, the spacing/alignment is not as expected. One can use the undocumented `\newcases` to define a comparable alternative. Below I've adapted `rcases` to have a right-aligned first column, and introduce a `\thickmuskip` between the two "columns", similar to what one would expect around ordinary and relation atoms:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\makeatletter
\newcases{Rcases}{$\mskip\thickmuskip$}{%
  \hfil$\m@th{##}$}{$\m@th{##}$\hfil}{.}{\rbrace}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{Rcases}
    a   &= x_{ij} \\
    b_j &= y_j
  \end{Rcases} \label{eq}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: could also mention `rcases` from `mathtools`...