# Referring to a whole eqnarray

Tags: hyperref, equations, amsmath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [numbering few equations together](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35295/numbering-few-equations-together)

I've got an `eqnarray` with multiple equations and a label on it, e.g.:

```
\begin{eqnarray}
  \hat{\delta}(q_0,\epsilon) & = & {\color{orange}q_0} & & & & \\
  \hat{\delta}(q_0,a)    & = & \delta(\hat{\delta}(q_0,\epsilon), a) & = & {\color{orange}\delta(q_0, a)} & = & q_1 \\
  \hat{\delta}(q_0,ac)   & = & \delta(\hat{\delta}(q_0, a), c)       & = & {\color{orange}\delta(q_1, c)} & = & q_1 \\
  \hat{\delta}(q_0,aca)  & = & \delta(\hat{\delta}(q_0, ac), a)      & = & {\color{orange}\delta(q_1, a)} & = & q_2 \\
  \hat{\delta}(q_0,acac) & = & \delta(\hat{\delta}(q_, aca) c)       & = & {\color{orange}\delta(q_2, c)} & = & q_2
  \label{eqn:automata-derivation}
\end{eqnarray}
```

The important part for me is the colorized as a whole, that means that the whole eqnarray is important and not a single line of it.

If I refer to the label `eqn:automata-derivation` the reference is just for the last line and every other line is counted apart from it (line 1: (1), line 2: (2), ... , line 5: (5), and if I refer to this only `5` would be shown).

What is the correct way:

- to count the whole eqnarray as one single equation and not every line each?
- to refer to it adequately?

Comment: You need the amsmath split environment. I'll put an example up in a second.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt I guess there already exist questions regarding one number for several equations, solved with `aligned` or `split`. We could look which one is good here, possible closing as duplicate.

Comment: ok, I haven't found it, if possible please post it.

Comment: Please have a look at [numbering few equations together](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35295/numbering-few-equations-together). Does it help with the problem, also regarding hyperref? Btw. better [avoid `eqnarray`](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/eqnarray-align-environment/).

Comment: Yes this does it thanks... I'm going to close this now.

Comment: @beyeran There's no need to delete. I undeleted it and closed it with a link to the duplicate. Your question is useful, because users could find it via a search engine and are directed to the solutions in the other question.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz: This is actually not trivial to solve with split, due to the multiple alignment (not possible in a single split). I have code good to go if it gets reopened.

Comment: Depending on what you're after the `subequations` environment from `amsmath` could also be interesting. Put the `align` within `subequations`, and the lines will be numbered 1a, 1b, etc. With a label outside `align` you'll get a reference to eq. 1.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt That's why we could use `aligned` or `alignedat` here. I understood the question was about referencing, not particularly about writing multiple equations with alignment, though it could help the OP. Perhaps we've got a link to a question where that is explained? Posting it in a comment could help. Otherwise, if you think, just click on *Vote to reopen* and I will gladly reopen it.