# Systems of equations with a single number

Tags: equations, numbering, arrays

I want to write a numbered system of equations. Right now, this is what I do and I am satisfied with the output, but I have a feeling it's not the best way to do it.

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{array}{ccl}
    a + b + c & = & d \\
    e + f     & = & g \\
    h         & = & i
  \end{array}
\end{equation}
```

How should I handle system of equations with a single number associated to it?

**UPDATE** :

I have read the [`asmmath` package documentation](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) and I feel more comfortable with what it offers. However, are there still some situations in which using the `array` environment is still relevant. For example, I would not know how to produce this result otherwise :

```
\begin{equation}
  \left\{
  \begin{array}{lcl}
    x_1 + x_2 + x_3 & = & 1 \\
    x_1 + x_2       & = & 2 \\
    x_1             & = & 3
  \end{array}
  \right.
\end{equation}
```

In the case the spacing seems correct, and it would not bee desirable to have the first column aligned to the `=` sign.

Comment: Better use the `split` environment of `amsmath` in the equation environment, or `aligned`. Have a look at the examples here and compare: [Difference between (split, align) and (gather, aligned)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63929/difference-between-split-align-and-gather-aligned). I'm sure this question has been asked before - perhaps somebody finds the duplicate, a better matching one than I linked?

Comment: See also [How can I number a few equations together](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35295/numbering-few-equations-together) and [How to get only one vertically centered equation number in align environment with two equations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/how-to-get-only-one-vertically-centered-equation-number-in-align-environment-wit).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: No, the spacing in the EDIT part is not correct. Use `\begin{array}{l@{}c@{}l}` and input lines like `x_1+x_2 & {}={} & 2`. You'll see the difference.

Comment: The correct math spacing with `array` can be achieved if you you use `\begin{array}{r@{}l}`, and then use `{}=` as in `a + b + c &{}= d`.

Answer (score 17):

The spacing is all wrong if you use an array, the AMS alignments provide alignment whilst preserving operator spacing:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{array}{ccl}
    a + b + c & = & d \\
    e + f     & = & g \\
    h         & = & i
  \end{array}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    a + b + c & =  d \\
    e + f     & =  g \\
    h         & =  i
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```