# Label a block or systems of equations with one label

Tags: cross-referencing, equations, align

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get only one vertically centered equation number in align environment with two equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/how-to-get-only-one-vertically-centered-equation-number-in-align-environment-wit)

I have a big system of equations which I want to label as one block. I do want to use `align` as the backbone of the typeset. I can produce, using `\nonumber`, something like

```
\begin{align}
a &= & b \nonumber\\
x+y & & =z\nonumber\\
w =& v & \nonumber\\
1 & 2 & 3
\label{eq1}
\eng{align}
```

However, this produces the label at the end, and I guess that a better look would be that the label will be typeset at the middle of the vertical height of the block. I tried to use a combination of `\equation` and `\split` but then I don't know how to take advantage of the columns available in `\align`.

So, how can I achieve this? If you think that this won't look good then what are the other possibilities I can take?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the "inner" version of `align`

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
a &= & b\\
x+y & & =z\\
w =& v & \\
1 & 2 & 3
\end{aligned}
\label{eq1}
\end{equation}
```