# Global label in a LaTeX “align”

Tags: equations, align, labels

I use

```
\begin{align}
\label{blah}
...
\end{align}
```

in order to do equations of multiple lines. Unfortunately the equation number (coming from `label{blah}`) is not centered vertically in the middle of the multiple lines. How to do this with `align` ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: Or this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/how-to-get-only-one-vertically-centered-equation-number-in-align-environment-wit?lq=1 ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! In order for the persons frequenting this site to able to help you, it's essential that you provide more information about the equations you have in the `align` environment: How many are there? An even or odd number of lines? Should there be a single equation number for *all* lines in the `align` structure, or are there groups of equations. Posting an MWE (minimum working example) would be really helpful.