# How to write in proper format of this code

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, align, algorithm2e

I want to get the right hand side portion in a format.
Here the format.

```
Table[i, j] <-maximum { Table[i-1, j]
                          AND
                       Values[i] + Table[i-1, j – Weights[i]]
```

It is not coming in a proper format.

```
Table[i,j] $\gets \max{(Table[i-1, j]

                          AND

                  \hfill \hfill   U[i] + Table[{i-1}, 
                \( \mathit{taskarea\textnormal{-}HS[i]}\)])}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

The example you showed has unbalanced braces and `$`.
Generally, if you want to to type multiline maths, it is *not* sufficient to separate the lines with blank line as you do in ordinary text. You need to use special environments like `align`, `gather`, `split`, `aligned`, `gathered` etc. The new lines / rows are signalled with `\\` instead of blank lines (like you do in tables). New columns are signalled with the `&` (like you do in tables).

Is this what you wanted? I am guessing that you need a multi line environment *inside* a math environment in order to split the argument of the `max` into three lines.

(https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112528/95229 and AMS math documentation -- 3.7
Alignment building blocks)

I have made only minimal adjustments since the meaning of the symbols in the equation are not known to me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
Table[i,j] \gets \max\left(
    \begin{gathered}[c]
       Table[i-1, j]\\
       \mathrm{AND}\\ %mathrm because It is an operator?
       U[i] + Table\Big[{i-1}, \mathit{taskarea\textnormal{-}HS[i]}\Big]
    \end{gathered}
    \right)
\end{align}

\begin{align}
Table[i,j] \gets \max\left(
    \begin{aligned}
        & Table[i-1, j]\\
        & \mathrm{AND}\\ %mathrm because It is an operator?
        & U[i] + Table\Big[{i-1}, \mathit{taskarea\textnormal{-}HS[i]}\Big]
    \end{aligned}
    \right)
\end{align}

\begin{align}
Table[i,j] \gets \max\left(
    \begin{aligned}
        Table[i-1, j]\\
        \mathrm{AND}\\ %mathrm because It is an operator?
        U[i] + Table\Big[{i-1}, \mathit{taskarea\textnormal{-}HS[i]}\Big]
    \end{aligned}
\right)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: different alignments]