# How can I label only one line of an equation array?

Tags: equations, numbering

Consider the following commands to create a labelled multi-line equation array:

```
\begin{eqnarray}
\label{eqn:1}
X&=&Y+Z\\
&\leq & U \times W.

\end{eqnarray}
```

It creates a two-line equations with two numbers. How can I associate only one equation number to this two-line equations? or better, how can I associated different equation numbers to each line? (of course, without breaking the equation array into several disjoint equations!)

Comment: Please don't use `eqnarray`. See [`\eqnarray` vs `\align`](http://goo.gl/3R7Ln).

Comment: I have the exact same question. Have to use `\eqnarray` because that's required by the journal template.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides a similar interface to `eqnarray`, but is better in terms of it's horizontal spacing/alignment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  X &= Y + Z \label{eqn:1} \\
    &\leq U \times W. \nonumber \\
    & = Y + Z \tag{a}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

`\nonumber` removes the number for that line in the `align` environment. `\tag` can also be used to create a manual tag.

Comment: Though I never use it myself.  I still forget when answering questions on this site that it's recommended not to use `eqnarray`.

Comment: `\tag*{a}` for labels without parentheses

Answer (score 7):

if only one equation number is wanted for a group, the `split` environment from
`amsmath` is a reasonable candidate; it must be "wrapped" in an `equation` environment for the equation number to appear.

if all the equations in a group are to be numbered, then (as pointed out in other answers)
the `align` environment is more suitable.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 X &=Y+Z\\
   &\leq U \times W
\end{split}
 \label{eqn:1}
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
 X &=Y+Z \label{eqn:2}\\
   &\leq U \times W \label{eqn:3}
\end{align}
```

[image: output of example code]

Answer (score 2):

Use `\notag`:

```
\begin{eqnarray}
\label{eqn:1}
X&=&Y+Z\\
\notag
&\leq & U \times W.    
\end{eqnarray}
```

But, as @werner reminds us, it is not advised to use `eqnarray`, `align` does a better job:

```
\begin{align}
\label{eqn:1}
     X & = Y + Z \\
\notag & \leq  U \times W.    
\end{align}
```

This requires that you load the package `amsmath` to have access to `\notag`

Math environments in LaTeX are not happy with empty lines.  If you want each line to have a number, just don't use `\notag`.

See [How to get only one vertically centered equation number in align environment with two equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13397/22413) for how to get one equation number for multiple lines.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I label each line individually?

Comment: @VahidShirbisheh -- instead of `\notag`, put a `\label` on the second line.  each line can be individually labeled for later reference.