# Line-breaking (splitting) an inequality

Tags: amsmath, mathtools, split

How can I split the following inequality across three lines?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray}\label{hhi1}
\frac{1}{q-p}\int_{p}^{q}\kappa(u)du\leq min\left\{\kappa(p)\int_{0}^{1} h(r)dr +m\varphi\bigg(\kappa(p),\kappa\Big(\frac{q}{m}\Big)\bigg)\int_{0}^{1} h(1-r)dr,\kappa(q)\int_{0}^{1} h(r)dr +m\varphi\bigg(\kappa(q),\kappa\Big(\frac{p}{m}\Big)\bigg)\int_{0}^{1} h(1-r)dr\right\}.
\end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, you definitely shouldn't use eqnarray; [see here](https://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/eqnarray-align-environment/). You should probably use a multline environment, though there are other options depending on what you want: see [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Aligning_equations_with_amsmath) and [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Aligning_equations_with_amsmath).

Comment: multline environment ended up with errors doesn't work dear, I have also tried \begin{split} . both are not working, but in the remaining document split environment is working very well.

Comment: "Ended up with errors" is unhelpful. What did you actually write and what errors did you get? (You can edit the question.) You may need to change `\left\{` and `\right\}` to `\Bigg\{` and `\Bigg\}` or do as FHZ suggests with regard to `\left` and `\right`.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution that nests an `aligned` environment inside a `multline` environment. This allows us to draw the reader's eye to the *structure* of the inequality.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline}\label{hhi1}
\frac{1}{q-p}\int_{p}^{q}\kappa(u)\,du  \\
\begin{aligned}[b]
\leq\min\biggl\{ 
&\kappa(p)\int_{0}^{1} h(r)\,dr 
 +m\varphi\Bigl(\kappa(p),\kappa\Bigl(\frac{q}{m}\Bigr)\Bigr)
 \int_{0}^{1} h(1-r)\,dr \,, \\
&\kappa(q)\int_{0}^{1} h(r)\,dr 
 +m\varphi\Bigl(\kappa(q),\kappa\Bigl(\frac{p}{m}\Bigr)\Bigr)
 \int_{0}^{1} h(1-r)\,dr \biggr\} \,.
\end{aligned}
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed, breaking at comma makes very clear where both arguments of `\min` are. I should have noticed that.

Answer (score 4):

One environment that breaks line is the `split`. It must be inside `equation`-like environment.

As you used `\left\{` at the beginning, you shall add `\right.` before ending and breaking the line (`\\`). If you don't, you get a error message: `Extra }, or forgotten \right. \end{split}`.
In consequence, as there must be a `\right\}` at the last line, there must be added a `\left.`.

Also notice that `\min` is a math command to write the word "min" as math function while just typing `min` may lead to a misleading "m" times "i" times "n".

Ampersand (`&`) is used to define the tabulation. I organized the sums below the `\leq` symbol.

You may also considere using `\mathrm{d}` to the `d`s of derivatives. Check [derivatives](https://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/derivative/derivative.pdf) for more information.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{hhi1}
  \begin{split}
    \frac{1}{q-p}\int_{p}^{q}\kappa(u)du & \leq \min \left\{ \kappa(p)\int_{0}^{1} h(r)dr \right. \\
    & +m\varphi\bigg(\kappa(p),\kappa\Big(\frac{q}{m}\Big)\bigg)\int_{0}^{1} h(1-r)dr,\kappa(q)\int_{0}^{1} h(r)dr \\
    & \left.+m\varphi\bigg(\kappa(q),\kappa\Big(\frac{p}{m}\Big)\bigg)\int_{0}^{1} h(1-r)dr \right\}.
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

#### Edit

Following David Carisle's advice, I change the `equation` block to

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    \frac{1}{q-p}\int_{p}^{q}\kappa(u)du & \leq \min \left\{ \kappa(p)\int_{0}^{1} h(r)dr \right.  \\
    & + m \varphi \left. \bigg(\kappa(p),\kappa\Big(\frac{q}{m}\Big)\bigg)\int_{0}^{1} h(1-r)dr,\kappa(q)\int_{0}^{1} h(r)dr \right. \\
    & + m \varphi \left. \bigg(\kappa(q),\kappa\Big(\frac{p}{m}\Big)\bigg)\int_{0}^{1} h(1-r)dr \right\}.
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

so that the spacing between `+`, `m \varphi` and the first `(` is not lost.

[image]

Comment: and how could I align all these toward the left?

Comment: The `&`s determine where things line up. If you want the `+`s to line up with the far left, move the first `&` before the initial `\frac`.

Comment: extra comments were very much informative @FHZ

Comment: is it right to do all this in the \begin{align} environment?

Comment: if you use `\left.` move the `+m` on the last row before it otherwise you lose the spacing, compare with the +m in the middle row

Answer (score 2):

A small variation of @mico answer:

- `multlined` (defined in `mathtools` package) is inserted in `equation` environment
- for fraction used in variables argument is used `\mfrac` (defined in the `nccmath` package):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{hhi1}
\begin{multlined}[0.9\linewidth]
    \frac{1}{q-p}\int_p^q \kappa(u)\, du    \\
    \leq    \min\biggl\{
        \kappa(p)\int_{0}^{1} h(r)\, dr + 
        m \varphi\left(\kappa(p),\kappa\Bigl(\mfrac{q}{m}\Bigr)\right)
        \int_{0}^{1} h(1-r)\, dr,           \\  
            \kappa(q)\int_0^1 h(r)\,dr + m \varphi\left(\kappa(q),\kappa\Bigl(\mfrac{p}{m}\Bigr)\right)
                 \int_0^1 h(1-r)\, dr
                 \biggr\}
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Is there an advantage to embedding a `multlined` environment in an `equation` environment over employing a single `multline` environment?

Comment: @Mico, actually not, I only see that equation number is vertical centering (what I prefer many times).

Answer (score 1):

As you asked if is it right using `align`, I'm adding this alternative answer using it.

Following [Mico's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/640960/140133) that highlights both parts of *\min*, and as `align` numbers each line, it would be nice to number each equation with some relevancy, not only a non-significant line, so I defined two generic variables `A` and `B` -- your functions with integrals -- and then the inequality is displayed using both `A` and `B` previously defined.

You may also [label each line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135567/how-can-i-label-only-one-line-of-an-equation-array) if needed.

*Note: It is not necessary to align all `&`s. They aligned because my editor does it with a simple button press.*

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  A                                    & = \kappa(p)\int_{0}^{1} h(r)dr + m \varphi \bigg(\kappa(p), \kappa \Big(\frac{q}{m}\Big)\bigg)\int_{0}^{1} h(1-r)dr \\
  B                                    & = \kappa(q)\int_{0}^{1} h(r)dr + m \varphi \bigg(\kappa(q), \kappa \Big(\frac{p}{m}\Big)\bigg)\int_{0}^{1} h(1-r)dr \\
  \frac{1}{q-p}\int_{p}^{q}\kappa(u)du & \leq \min \left\{A, B \right\}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hm, you probably mean @Mico answer :-). I didn't answer on this question (yet) ;-)

Comment: Oh... My mistake.