# How to make an align environment with multiple equations per line and one equation reference?

Tags: equations, align

I would like to use an align environment with a single equation number but with multiple equations per line. For example, the following two pieces of code work:

```
begin{align}
a&= 1 & b&= 2 + 3\\
c&= 4 + 5 & d&= 6\
\end{align}

begin{align}\begin{split}
a&= 1\\
c&= 4 + 5
\end{split}\end{align}
```

The second example succeeds in having one equation reference in the middle, and the first succeeds in having multiple equations per line. How might I have multiple equations per line with one equation reference? Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. Anyways, it seems that this solves the problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13396 Please confirm whether it solves your problem or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  a &= 1
&
  b &= 2 + 3
\\
  c &= 4 + 5
&
  d &= 6
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: The link does indeed answer my question, should I delete this entire question?

Comment: @Mark It is not necessary to delete the question.