# Equation broken into two (centered) lines with equation number in the middle of both lines

Tags: equations, numbering

I would like to know how to break a long equation into two lines and have both lines centered. Besides, I would like to have only one equation number in the middle of both lines.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts, amsthm, amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}



\noindent Text text text text text text text:
%
\begin{align}
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890=\\
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890\text{.}
\end{align}
%
Text text text text text text text.



\end{document}
```

I found something here: [How to get only one vertically centered equation number in align environment with two equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/how-to-get-only-one-vertically-centered-equation-number-in-align-environment-wit?rq=1).

In the link above the accepted answer explains how to have only one equation number in the middle of both lines. But I would like to have both lines centered, not aligned.

Comment: Can you make an example with TeX code?

Comment: Ok, I'll do it in a minute.

Comment: @egreg I added a MWE.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason when the equation is the last thing on the page, the equation number appears below the second line of the equation.

Comment: If the object is too wide and there's no space for the equation number, it's shifted down; it doesn't depend on the position on the page.

Comment: @egreg That's right! I had used `gathered` before and it worked and now it was not working. Now I realize it's because I had changed font size from `11pt` to `12pt`, so things had changed.

Comment: So I broke the equation in a different way and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 3):

`amsmath` has documentation explaining a number of different environments and is worth a look. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts, amsthm, amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

  \noindent Text text text text text text text:
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
      123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890=\\
      123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890\text{.}
    \end{split}
  \end{equation}
  Text text text text text text text.

\end{document}
```

[image: split equation]

Comment: Or `gathered` if right alignment of the two pieces is not wanted.

Comment: Or `multline`??

Answer (score 1):

This uses the `\Centerstack` macro of `stackengine`.  The distance between baselines is set with `\setstackgap{L}{}` to 14pt.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\noindent Text text text text text text text:
%
\begin{equation}
\setstackgap{L}{14pt}
\Centerstack{123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890=\\
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890\text{.}}
\end{equation}
%
Text text text text text text text.
\end{document}
```

[image]