# Referring to a system of equation from aligned environment

Tags: cross-referencing, align

I have a system of equations and I used aligned environment to get a one number as label [se here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/how-to-get-only-one-vertically-centered-equation-number-in-align-environment-wit/13397) but I am not able to refer to it. I searched here and other places but all shows how to refer to equation when it is labeled using \label. However using label in aligned environment with \begin equation doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper, twoside]{report} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} 
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d\bar{x}(\tau)}{d\tau}=\quad&\bar{x}\left[1-\bar{x}-\bar {y}_{1}-\bar{y} _{2} \right] +\bar{s}(\tau),\quad \bar{x}(0)>0\\
\frac{d\bar{y}_{1}(\tau)}{d\tau}=\quad& \bar{y}_{1} \left[-\bar{\epsilon}_{1}-\bar{\omega}_{11}\bar {y}_{1}-\bar{g}_{12}\bar{y}_{2}+\bar{\beta}_{1}\bar{x}\right],\quad \bar{y}_{1}(0)>0 \\
\frac{d\bar{y}_{2}(\tau)}{d\tau}=\quad& \bar{y}_{2} \left[-\bar{\epsilon}_{2}+\bar{\gamma_{12}}\bar{y}_{1}-\bar{\omega}_{22}\bar {y}_{2}+\bar{\beta}_{2}\bar{x}\right],\quad \bar{y}_{2}(0)>0 \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

In my document the system get the label (5.1) because it is inside chapter 5 but I want to refer to this other places. I can of course just write (5.1) but want more systematic way.

Comment: Not actually . How to use this?

Comment: I believe you can put `\ref{label}` inside the equation and then reference it elsewhere using `\eqref{label}`.

Comment: @ bclzyjhr  I tried to use label but nothing comes out.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I meant to say use `\label{text}` in the equation environment, then refer to it with `\eqref{text}` outside.

Comment: I I see it works but this is not very convenient because setting label using \ label doesn't change the automated label from the chapter.

Comment: your question is most unclear as your example doesn't use any label. But the labelling  is unrelated to the  `aligned` which does not affect the number or cross reference a at all. Just  use `\begin{equation}\label{zzzz}` then reference it as   `... see \eqref{zzzz}` from the text.

Comment: If I put `\label{eq:pft}` after `\begin{equation}` and `\eqref{eq:pft}` somewhere e.g. after `\end{equation}`, I get a reference. It is just an unfortunate practice to use one equation number (rather than `subequations`), but not as bad as non-upright differential `d`s.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I used the idea mentioned her  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/how-to-get-only-one-vertically-centered-equation-number-in-align-environment-wit/13397

Comment: but you say you have a problem with cross references but give no example of that use or show the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the equation number using `\label` and `\ref` (or `\eqref` which adds parenthesis) the fact that the equation contains an `aligned` does not affect things at all.

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper, twoside]{report} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{foo}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d\bar{x}(\tau)}{d\tau}=\quad&\bar{x}\left[1-\bar{x}-\bar {y}_{1}-\bar{y} _{2} \right] +\bar{s}(\tau),\quad \bar{x}(0)>0\\
\frac{d\bar{y}_{1}(\tau)}{d\tau}=\quad& \bar{y}_{1} \left[-\bar{\epsilon}_{1}-\bar{\omega}_{11}\bar {y}_{1}-\bar{g}_{12}\bar{y}_{2}+\bar{\beta}_{1}\bar{x}\right],\quad \bar{y}_{1}(0)>0 \\
\frac{d\bar{y}_{2}(\tau)}{d\tau}=\quad& \bar{y}_{2} \left[-\bar{\epsilon}_{2}+\bar{\gamma_{12}}\bar{y}_{1}-\bar{\omega}_{22}\bar {y}_{2}+\bar{\beta}_{2}\bar{x}\right],\quad \bar{y}_{2}(0)>0 \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

see \eqref{foo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that I have got the number  (5.1) in the middle (the same place you wrote (1) in your answer  without using \label in my equation and setting \label with whatever doesn't change it but I do can refer to it using what is written inside \label.

Comment: I'm not qualified to say whether or not adding a brace on the right of this group would be mathematically appropriate, but it would tie them together in a manner that highlights the single equation number.  (`rcases`)

Comment: @F.O sorry I can not understand that comment at all. `\label` has _no effect_ on the printed number it is the internal key (like `<p id="foo">` in html) for cross referencing. _You_ supplied this example and it has no chapters and only one equation so it's numbered (1) your real document may have chapters and the equation gets number 5.1 that is fine, the exact same `\label` construct will then make `\ref` produce (5.1) not (1)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I got confused because I thougt that \label should also change the equation number but I am wrong . Thanks for clarification.